# relative paths ms word and excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, relative-path

at my work, we deal with a large number or projects that we have created a "Template" folder layout with all the documents etc in the desired sub folders. In most of these documents we have to enter in the same information about the project, such as project name, number etc. this just adds time to completing these documents and I am trying to find a way to speed things up.
What I want to do is to have a single excel file that I can populate all the generic information in, then update all the word docs and excel docs that are in the template folder so they just read the information from the link.

I can get this to work by copying and pasting the link to the word doc or excel file, but this copies the absolute path, meaning when I copy the template folder to make a new folder for a new project, that the link is still pointing to the one in the template folder. oh, the other thing is that these folders will be on a server with multiple people accessing them, but only one person would be creating the project folder from the template folder.
is there anyway that I can make the path look to the parent directory that will allow me to copy and folder and bring the links up. our template folder is fairly complex and I cant really changes this. but bellow is an idea of how I want it to be set up. "info.xlsx" would be the workbook where I want to edit and link all the other files to.

```
Project x
.Info.xlsx
.Documents
..Saftey
..."SWMS.xlsx"
..Reports
...Compliance 
...."Form21.docx"
..Purchasing
..."PO-1092.xlsx"
```

Comment: Ask separately, please, for Word and for Excel. It's unlikely that the same person can provide an answer for both applications.

Answer (score 0):

In a excel you can use this formula to get the directory path where the workbook is saved.

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1),1)-1)
```

This one will give you 1 directory up from the parent. Changing the -1- to -2- will give you 2 levels up and so forth.

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),1,SEARCH("^^",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"\","^^",LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-1-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename",A1),"\","")))))
```